# java app running in screen starts a process and this child is NOT in screen

Tags: bash, process, gnu-screen, minecraft

I'm running a spigot server in screen, it is a java app. When it crashes and goes down gracefully it calls a restart script as a last action.

This script simply contains a `java -jar spigot.jar`. The problem is whenever the server goes down, *it restarts itself out of screen*. Not good, I want the restarted process to run in the same screen.

I tried the good old `screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'java -jar spigot.jar^M'` trick, but it sent the string to the java app console, not the command line.

So I tried to detach this call from the parent, this trick theoretically does it: `(sleep 20&);java -jar spigot.jar`, but no result.

So... I really do not know what to do. Please recommend.

Comment: I am not expert with *nix family OSs' but it may be storing the default position on screen in some configuration file. See if you can find anything.

Comment: Who is responsible for the restart ? Java app itself or bash script ?. How to know when java app crashes ?

Comment: the java app starts the script, and java knows when it goes down gracefully

Comment: I guess I got to write a script with an infinite loop monitoring the process and initiate start when it is not present... but it is not very umm... professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it sent the string to the java app console, not the command line.

The java need some time to exit.
Restart script `bash -c "sleep 20;  screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'java -jar spigot.jar^M' "`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Creates detached session named spigot
screen -S spigot -d -m
# Runs "java -jar spigot.jar" in spigot session
screen -S spigot -X stuff "java -jar spigot.jar^M"
```

Comment: yes, that's what I tried, it sends the `"java -jar spigot.jar^M"` to the java app console, not the shell in screen

Comment: Can you describe more precisely how you script and java app works and interact with each over?

Comment: * start a screen
* java -jar executable.jar
* jar gets into restart stage
* jar gracefully stops, and as a last action calls a bash script
* bash script executes java -jar executable.jar